# Accumulate exceptions to add them in the same REST response

Tags: spring-boot, rest, java-17, exceptionhandler

I'm trying to intercept all exceptions that can happen in a REST API request, create a custom message to each one and to add them both to the response.

The request below has two errors, one in the field `tipo` and other in the field `formato`. The default behavior is to stop in the first exception and throw. And after this the deserialization of the request stops. But I want to intercept the two exceptions and accumulate them to show both custom messages in the response.

```json
{
    "titulo": "1984",
    "autor": "Georgesss Orwell",
    "editora": "Penguin Classics Companhia das Letras",
    "tipo": "LIVsRO",
    "formato": "FISIsCO",
    "quantidadePaginas": "392",
    "edicao": 1,
    "anoEdicao": 2020,
    "generos": ["Literatura britânica", "Ficção", "Ficção britânica", "Distopia"],
    "acabamento": "BROCHURA",
    "idioma": "PORTUGUES",
    "pais": "BRASIL",
    "quantideLivros": 1
}
```

I'm using Java 17 with Spring Boot 2.7.5 in Windows 10.

Below is the approach that I've tried:

I've created a Global Exception Handler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
        exceptions.add(ex);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Erro na desserialização do JSON");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex) {
        exceptions.add(ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Erro interno do servidor");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccumulatedExceptions.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccumulatedExceptions(AccumulatedExceptions ex) {
        List<String> exceptionMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Exception exception : ex.getExceptions()) {
            exceptionMessages.add(exception.getMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(exceptionMessages);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void clearExceptions() {
        exceptions.clear();
    }

    public List<Exception> getExceptions() {
        return exceptions;
    }

}
```

With this custom exception:

```java
public class AccumulatedExceptions extends RuntimeException {
    private List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

    public AccumulatedExceptions(List<Exception> exceptions) {
        this.exceptions = exceptions;
    }

    public List<Exception> getExceptions() {
        return exceptions;
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "livros")
@CrossOrigin
public class LivroController {

    @Autowired
    private LivroService service;

    @Autowired
    private LivroRepository livroRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LivroResponse response;

    private GlobalExceptionHandler globalExceptionHandler;

    public LivroController(GlobalExceptionHandler globalExceptionHandler) {
        this.globalExceptionHandler = globalExceptionHandler;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "getLivros")
    public List<Livro> getLivros() {
        return livroRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "addLivro")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addLivro(@RequestBody LivroRequest request) {

            List<Exception> exceptions = globalExceptionHandler.getExceptions();
            if (!exceptions.isEmpty()) {
               globalExceptionHandler.clearExceptions();
               throw new AccumulatedExceptions(exceptions);
           }

           return ResponseEntity.ok("Livro criado com sucesso");

    }

}
```

Is it possible to do what I want or did I go crazy?

Let me know if you need more information from my side.

Thanks in advance.